# clicking on tab to execute Javascript functions to populate divs is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to have tabs and when clicked on a tab, I need to be able to execute jquery scripts to populate divs within each tab. when I switch over to other tab, other tab data should be displayed on the div. I have this script to hide and display data for the active tab:

```
<script>
    // Wait until the DOM has loaded before querying the document
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('ul.tabs').each(function () {
            // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
            // which tab is active and it's associated content
            var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

            // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
            // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
            $active = $($links.filter('[href="' + location.hash + '"]')[0] || $links[0]);
            $active.addClass('active');
            $content = $($active.attr('href'));

            // Hide the remaining content
            $links.not($active).each(function () {
                $($(this).attr('href')).hide();

            });

            // Bind the click event handler
            $(this).on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                // Make the old tab inactive.
                $active.removeClass('active');
                $content.hide();

                // Update the variables with the new link and content
                $active = $(this);
                $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

                // Make the tab active.
                $active.addClass('active');
                $content.show();

                // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is the html:

```
<ul class='tabs'>
    <li><a  href='#tab1'>SITEPERFORMANCE</a></li>
    <li><a  href='#tab2'>DB</a></li>
    <li><a  href='#tab3'>WEB</a></li>


  <div id="tab2">
    <div id="container">
        <table align="center">
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <div class="zoom_controls">
                          <div class="zoom_controls">
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_cpu_d" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="1m">Real Time</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_cpu_w"href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="3m">Weekly</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_cpu_m" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="6m">Monthly</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_cpu_f"href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="All">Forecast</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="container_cpu" style="width:700px; height:300px;"></div></td>  
            </tr>
        </table>    
        <br>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <div class="zoom_controls">
                          <div class="zoom_controls">
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_pc_d" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="1m">Real Time</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_pc_w"href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="3m">Weekly</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_pc_m" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="6m">Monthly</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_pc_f"href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="All">Forecast</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="container_pc" style="width:700px; height:300px;"></div></td>   
            </tr>
        </table>    
        <br>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <div class="zoom_controls">
                          <div class="zoom_controls">
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_mem_d" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="1m">Real Time</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_mem_w"href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="3m">Weekly</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_mem_m" href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="6m">Monthly</a>
                              <a class="DB" id="prof_mem_f"href="#" data-chart="line" data-range="All">Forecast</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="container_memory" style="width:700px; height:300px;"></div></td>   
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
</div>
```

I also have this piece of little jquery to execute some functions and load the divs when clicked on the tab:

```
$("#tab2").click(function () {
    db_cpu();
    db_pc();
    db_memory();
});
```

db_cpu(), db_pc(), db_memory() functions that create charts and populate the corresponding divs (these functions work).

When I click on tab2, I dont get the divs populated. But when click on inner divs like prof_cpu_d, it works. I need to populate the divs when I clicked on the tabs. Any idea how I would call db_cpu, db_pc and db_memory when clicked on tab2?

If I click on any where in the body of the page, the divs load up?Does this have to do with any caching? is there a way to force the first time load when clicking on the tab div?

This is the css for tabs:

```
.tabs li {
                                    list-style:none;
                                    display:inline;
                                }

                            .tabs a {
                                    padding:5px 10px;
                                    display:inline-block;
                                    background:#C0C0C0;
                                    color:#000;
                                    text-decoration:none;
                                    text-align: center;
                                    font: 18px sans serif;
                                    font-weight: bold;

                                }

                            .tabs a.active {
                                    background:#6E6EFF;
                                    color:#fff;
                                }
```

Comment: You're missing the `</ul>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

try following: change

```
<li><a  href='#tab1'>SITEPERFORMANCE</a></li>
<li><a  href='#tab2'>DB</a></li>
<li><a  href='#tab3'>WEB</a></li>
```

to

```
<li id='anchor_tab1'>SITEPERFORMANCE</li>
<li id='anchor_tab2'>DB</li>
<li id='anchor_tab3'>WEB</li>
```

and access the function with

```
$('#anchor_tabX').click(...);
```

can you post your css you are using for hiding and showing your tabs?

Comment: it did not work. Also, if I do it your way, I lose the tab functionality.

Comment: did you change your script to find span-tags instead of a-tags:
var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('span');

Comment: how should be the html, above line does not work - <a id='tab2'>DB</a>

Comment: I posted the css. Also, when I try this, I lose the tab functionlity.

Comment: do you load the content of the tabs dynamically or at page load?

Comment: Fist time for the page load  for the default tab and after all dynamic. My original post is almost working but not quite . I think there is some caching issue. When I click the tab it does not but after clicking the tab and clicking anywhere in the body loads the divs.

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

```
$("a[href=#tab2]").click(function() {
functions()
});
```